# Iterate over an excel file and create a new dictionary for every new item in a column

Tags: python-3.x, excel, dictionary, openpyxl

Broadly speaking I'm trying to take an excel file that contains our inventory and create different dictionaries for each location containing the {hostename : ip_address} for each switch in that location.

Ideally I'd like it to work something along the lines of

```
for row in range(1, worksheet.max_row + 1):
    if cell.column == existing_dictionary_name
        continue
    else
        cell.column = {}
    
    key = worksheet.cell(row, #).value
    value = worksheet.cell(row, #).value
    cell.column[key] = value
```

I tried the following

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

workbook = load_workbook(filename="Test db.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.active
host_ip = {}

for row in range(1, worksheet.max_row + 1):
    key = worksheet.cell(row, 4).value
    value = worksheet.cell(row, 2).value
    dict_name = worksheet.cell(row, 6).value
    dict_name[key] = value

print(a)
print(b)
Print(c)
```

but I just get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 20, in <module>
    dict_name[key] = value
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: ``dict_name`` isn't a dictionary, it's a ``str`` object. You would need to change ``dict_name[key] = value`` to ``host_ip[key] = value``.

Comment: `host_ip[dict_name] = {key:value}`

Comment: Hello @Simon1 I'm trying to get this to create a new dictionary each time it finds a location that doesn't already have one.

For this the excel file looks like

Switch1 192.168.1.1   a
switch2 192.168.1.2   a
switch3 192.168.1.3   b
switch4 192.168.1.4   b
switch5 192.168.1.5   c
switch6 192.168.1.6   c

And I want to have it creat dictionary a, b, and c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not easy creating a variable name with a name from input, but if you can settle for a dict of dicts, then it becomes a lot easier.

This uses a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) defaulting to `dict` itself as the overall holder.

The iterates through the rows with [`iter_rows`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.iter_rows), skipping the header row and returning values only. Every iteration updates the `dict` for the row's location with the switch and ip values.

With this input:

| switch | ip | location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| switch1 | 192.168.1.1 | a |
| switch2 | 192.168.1.2 | a |
| switch3 | 192.168.1.3 | b |
| switch4 | 192.168.1.4 | c |
| switch5 | 192.168.1.5 | b |

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from collections import defaultdict

net_locations = defaultdict(dict)

wb = load_workbook("/tmp/75072112.xlsx")
ws = wb.active

for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, values_only=True):
    net_locations[row[2]].update({row[0]: row[1]})

net_locations

# defaultdict(dict,
#             {'a': {'switch1': '192.168.1.1', 'switch2': '192.168.1.2'},
#              'b': {'switch3': '192.168.1.3', 'switch5': '192.168.1.5'},
#              'c': {'switch4': '192.168.1.4'}})
```